# adding data to firebase realtime database from an object (web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object containing multiple key value pairs, I want to add all the keys and their values, from inside the object to an existing node, without disturbing the data already present inside the node.

If i write like this

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("hams/spam_words/");

    ref.update({   

       new_words_ham //new_word_ham is an object containing n number of words

    });
```

it will add new_words_ham as another child node inside the main node , i cannot have that

even using a forloop on the object does not work

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("hams/spam_words/");
    for(var i in new_words_ham){
        var word = i
    ref.update({   
      i
    });
```

I am new to js as well as to firebase. Please do tell me if i have got any concept wrong

Comment: also can some one just tell me if i am using the terms node and child in the wrong sense here

Comment: This statement looks a bit strange `ref.update({ new_words_ham });` Are the wrapping curly brackets a typo or is removing them solving your problem?

Comment: @DennisAlund modern JavaScript allows `{ new_words_ham }` as a shorthand for `{ new_words_ham: new_words_ham } `. Yes, I find it incredibly hard to get used to too. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that, I learned something interesting from this 

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code

```
//new_word_ham is an object containing n number of words
firebase.database().ref("hams/spam_words/").update({   
   new_words_ham 
});
```

Can be rewritten as

```
firebase.database().ref("hams/spam_words/").update({   
   new_words_ham: new_words_ham
});
```

when the shorthand syntax is expanded. What I believe you want is simply

```
firebase.database().ref("hams/spam_words/").update(new_words_ham);
```